# Allow people to see my sites on WAMP

Tags: port-forwarding, port

I currently setup a port in my router. Port Number is `2300` and I wanted to share a site on my WAMP server. I know how to setup port forwarding so that can't be the issue. But when I go to `{My-IP}:2300` I just get "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to {MY-IP}:2300". I changed `Listen 80` to `Listen 2300` in the Apache `httpd.conf` file. I used a port checker to see if my port goes through and it did, so the port seems to be working for the port checker, but not for me.

[image]

Comment: What about TCP connections ?

Comment: I only set it up with udp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you testing this from inside your own network? If so, then you'd need a router that supports hairpin routing (which most consumer-grade "routers" don't support).